# NSDateFormatter setDateFormat parameters

Tags: objective-c

In php there is a list of all the parameters you can pass to the date function to format your date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Is there something similar for objective c?

Comment: @IuliusCæsar but are the format specifiers in the Apple docs? I've never found them there.

Comment: @yuji: The [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW4) contains links to the formatters at unicode.org

Comment: I'd already looked at the docs but there isn't a list like the php one I posted a link to.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar ahh true fair enough

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's one: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/

> Ever wonder just what you could put in NSDateFormatter [format strings](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)? Enough to actually go to the trouble of actually dumping specifiers and results? Nah, us neither. But somebody did, and here’s what they found:
>
> ```
> a: AM/PM
> A: 0~86399999 (Millisecond of Day)
>
> c/cc: 1~7 (Day of Week)
> ccc: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat
> cccc: Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday
>
> d: 1~31 (0 padded Day of Month)
> D: 1~366 (0 padded Day of Year)
>
> e: 1~7 (0 padded Day of Week)
> E~EEE: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat
> EEEE: Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday
>
> F: 1~5 (0 padded Week of Month, first day of week = Monday)
>
> g: Julian Day Number (number of days since 4713 BC January 1)
> G~GGG: BC/AD (Era Designator Abbreviated)
> GGGG: Before Christ/Anno Domini
>
> h: 1~12 (0 padded Hour (12hr))
> H: 0~23 (0 padded Hour (24hr))
>
> k: 1~24 (0 padded Hour (24hr)
> K: 0~11 (0 padded Hour (12hr))
>
> L/LL: 1~12 (0 padded Month)
> LLL: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec
> LLLL: January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/December
>
> m: 0~59 (0 padded Minute)
> M/MM: 1~12 (0 padded Month)
> MMM: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec
> MMMM: January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/December
>
> q/qq: 1~4 (0 padded Quarter)
> qqq: Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4
> qqqq: 1st quarter/2nd quarter/3rd quarter/4th quarter
> Q/QQ: 1~4 (0 padded Quarter)
> QQQ: Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4
> QQQQ: 1st quarter/2nd quarter/3rd quarter/4th quarter
>
> s: 0~59 (0 padded Second)
> S: (rounded Sub-Second)
>
> u: (0 padded Year)
>
> v~vvv: (General GMT Timezone Abbreviation)
> vvvv: (General GMT Timezone Name)
>
> w: 1~53 (0 padded Week of Year, 1st day of week = Sunday, NB: 1st week of year starts from the last Sunday of last year)
> W: 1~5 (0 padded Week of Month, 1st day of week = Sunday)
>
> y/yyyy: (Full Year)
> yy/yyy: (2 Digits Year)
> Y/YYYY: (Full Year, starting from the Sunday of the 1st week of year)
> YY/YYY: (2 Digits Year, starting from the Sunday of the 1st week of year)
>
> z~zzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Abbreviation)
> zzzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Name)
> Z: +0000 (RFC 822 Timezone)
> ```
>
> That should settle your date and time formatting needs once and for all!
>
> UPDATES:
>
> [Swiftly getting a human-readable date with NSDateFormatter](http://nsdateformatter.com/)...

Comment: Thanks that was just what I was after.

Apart from, is there a parameter for the date suffix e.g. th, st, rd

I couldn't see one on the list.

Comment: That site is very hard to follow.

Comment: This answer isn't exactly accurate. If you want zero-padding you must always repeat the specific character.

For example, to pad minutes you must put "mm", not just "m" (the difference between "05" and "5"). This follows for d, D, h, H, k, K, m, s, and presumably w.

Answer (score -1):

The definitive list, from unicode.org is at http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns